# close one tabslideout when another tabslideout is open

Tags: jquery

I am using two tabslideout plugin, this is work fine, but main problem when one tabslideout  is open another is not close, still two tabslideout  is open. i want to when one tabslideout is open another remains close.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
        tabHandle: '.mailing_list',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
        pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
        imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
        imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
        tabLocation: 'right',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
        speed: 500,                               //speed of animation
        action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
        topPos: '200px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
        leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
        fixedPosition: false,                      //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
        toogleHandle: true
    });

    jQuery('.slide-out-div-social-media').tabSlideOut({
        tabHandle: '.mailing_list_social-media',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
        pathToTabImage: 'images/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
        imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
        imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
        tabLocation: 'right',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
        speed: 500,                               //speed of animation
        action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
        topPos: '200px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
        leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
        fixedPosition: false,                      //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
        toogleHandle: true
    });
```

Comment: Your plugin probably has a general way to open and close a slideout. Every time you call a slideout (?click), just close all slideouts, then open the one you want. To be more specific, we'll need the code where you call the slideouts, not just the slideout styling.

Comment: <div class="slide-out-div">
 <a class="mailing_list">One</a>
 <div class="mailinglist">
  Content of first DIV
 </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-out-div-social-media">
 <a class="mailing_list_social-media">Two</a>
 <div class="mailinglist">
  Content of Two DIV
 </div>
</div>

Comment: This is my styleing code

Comment: I think what we need to see is which plugin you are using, and how you call the slider. Is it with a hover? click?